# jquery animate top vs marginTop

Tags: jquery, html

i am having the strangest problem with jQuery animate
when i use `marginTop` it works but just `top` does nothing
heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/nnqt6/1/
any suggestions why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nnqt6/3/

You need a `position: relative;` attached the each of the li's which will animate down.  The top CSS parameter can't be changed like this unless it's top position is relative to another element.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
.otherBtns{position:relative;}
```